# Name a function after a string

Tags: python

I am trying to read different tabs from an excel file.
For each tab I a want to perform a linear regression that returns a function (1st order polynom)
I want to store the function under the name of tab or the data frame

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


dfs = pd.read_excel(r'Prod.xlsx', sheet_name=None)
for df in dfs:
     func = np.poly1d(np.polyfit(dfs[df].P, dfs[df].Q, 1))
     def df(x):
         return func(x)
```

I would like to have a function with an individual name for regression each of the sheets. I tried also

```
for df in dfs:
     df = np.poly1d(np.polyfit(dfs[df].P, dfs[df].Q, 1))
```

but the problem is that df is being overwritten!

Comment: I'm really confused about what you're trying to achieve - could you give an example of how you'd like to be able to use these functions afterwards?

Comment: Sounds like the "variable variables" problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-variable-variables

Comment: I assume you want to have a dictionary `polynomials`, where the key is the column name inside the dataframe, while the value is the corresponding polynomial?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to store the function under the name of tab or the data frame

I think you just want a dictionary of functions:

```py
polynomial_functions = {}
tabs = pd.read_excel(r'Prod.xlsx', sheet_name=None)
for tab in tabs:
     func = np.poly1d(np.polyfit(dfs[df].P, dfs[df].Q, 1))
     polynomial_functions[tab] = func
```

Then you can call later with

```py
polynomial_functions["tab_name"]()
```

Note that I've renamed your `df` to `tab` to make it clearer what a dataframe represents.